# change product price based on the delivery datetime

Tags: module, price, catalog-price-rules, delivery-time

I am new on Magento.
I would like to ask how do I change the product's price based on delivery date time.

In my Magento's development, the customer can choose a store, and then select "pickup now" or "scheduled deliver datetime". The price will be changed according to selected delivery datetime.

Is there any method without using extension?

Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: Based on the selection, you want to change product price or your delivery price?

Comment: delivery price, thanks

Comment: How currently you added those delivery charge?

Comment: there is no delivery charge, only the product price. because the store only provides pickup, but customer can choose the time when they pick up the product. pickup time = delivery datetime

Comment: I as asking about Store Pickup options only, you need to added charge for that one.

Comment: sorry, can you explain more with adding the charge. thanks very much